# How to import geometry nodes into new file

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have grouped my geometry nodes, and Im trying to import the geo nodes via append, but I dont see the nodes applied to by Bezier curve.

[image]
[image]

Ill upload the file for better insight.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to actually select the node tree data block for use, in the Node Editor. It’s that way for all other non-object data blocks.

Comment: in your new file go to append -> choose your file -> node tree  -> choose your gn node tree